# Ruby on Rails - Different elements for each do slices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, each

In my application I do `each_slice` and then `each_with_index` because of some stuff I'm doing in my application.

*My current code is like this:*

```
- @images.each_slice(@album.images_per_page <= 2 ? 1 : 2) do |group|
  - group.each_with_index do |img, i|
    .col-md-2
      /* Ads Left */
    .col-md-7
      = image_tage img.image_url(:thumb)
    .col-md-3
      /* Ads Right */
```

Usually I show 4 images on every page. The first 3 will have ads inside `.col-md-2` & `.col-md-3`. What I want to achieve is to add different ads-codes/type for each element.

For instance, First image would have *300x250 tag*, second image *300x600* and third would have *content-type ads (Taboola)* and not showing any ads after these 3.

*I tried: (Ex. 1)*

```
- if i == 0
  %h1 300x250
- elsif i == 1
  %h1 300x600
- elsif i == 2
  %h1 Taboola
```

*and (Ex. 2)*

```
- if i+1 == group.length
  %h1 i+1 = group.length
```

But I don't get what I'm looking for. Ex.1 takes every 1 element and adds *300x250* & every 2nd element and adds *300x600*, So I don't get *Taboola* and gets double of *300x250* & *300x600* while Ex.2 takes every 2nd element and adds only *300x250*.

*Ex.1 results becomes this:*

```
Image 1 => 300x250
Image 2 => 300x600
Image 3 => 300x250
Image 4 => 300x600
```

*Ex.2 results becomes this:*

```
Image 1 => /* Nothing */
Image 2 => 300x250
Image 3 => /* Nothing */
Image 4 => 300x250
```

How can I achieve so I can choose what ad I want to show on each element?

*Result I'm looking for:*

```
Image 1 => 300x250
Image 2 => 300x600
Image 3 => Taboola
Image 4 => /* Nothing */
```

*Hope I could explain what I'm looking for.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal should be to leave as few logic as possible in views. Complex logic should be done in model/controller/helpers.

Here's a possibility with [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) :

```
@images = %w(imageA imageB imageC imageD)

params = [
  ['300x250','r1'],
  ['300x600','r2'],
  ['Taboola','r3']
]

@images.zip(params).each_with_index do |(image, param), i|
  left, right = param
  puts "Image : #{image}"
  puts "ParamL: #{left}"
  puts "ParamR: #{right}"
  puts "Index : #{i}"
  puts "Even? : #{i.even?}"
  puts
end
```

It outputs :

```
Image : imageA
ParamL: 300x250
ParamR: r1
Index : 0
Even? : true

Image : imageB
ParamL: 300x600
ParamR: r2
Index : 1
Even? : false

Image : imageC
ParamL: Taboola
ParamR: r3
Index : 2
Even? : true

Image : imageD
ParamL: 
ParamR: 
Index : 3
Even? : false
```

It seems to be enough information for what you want to do.

Also, you're calling `each_slice` with either 1 or 2 as parameter. `each_slice(1)` is basically useless, `each_slice(2)` would just split your array in pairs. Checking if `id` is odd or even should give you just as much information, without needing another nested block.

`each_slice(2)` is also the reason why your index stays equal to `0` or `1`. It cannot be equal to 2, so your `Taboola` case never happened.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Eric. I have one last question. inside the `zip` you have the `array` for ads that goes to `.col-md-2 Left side ads`. In that array how can I also have ads for `.col-md-3 Right side ads`. The ads on right side will also be in same way as *Left side ads*. I can add the array to my `helper`. I added the code inside a `nested array` and did this: `param[0][2]` But I get error: `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` in Rails

Comment: Same as left side with different ads type & sizes. My array now looks like: `[['300x250', 'ads left 1'], ['300x600', 'ads left 2'],['Taboola', 'ads left 1']]` and I have the array in my `helper`

Comment: Updated. The nested array is a good idea, but `param[0][2]` could fail because `param[0]` can be nil.

Comment: Great. Works like a charm :) Appreciate your help